# Do authors normally check their own papers for plagiarism?

Tags: peer-review, plagiarism

I was recently asked to review a paper (for a very reputable journal). In the cover letter, it says

> "This paper has been checked with [turnitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnitin) to ensure there is no similarity to other papers."

I haven't seen this before (although I have limited reviewing experience). Is this normal? Or does this indicate something strange about the author?

I've never checked any of my own papers for plagiarism. Should I?

EDIT: Also, why would you mention this in the cover letter?

Comment: It is a sort of reflection in response to the modern plagiarism related hysterics. No, it is not usual. Yet.

Comment: It is very common for editors to check for plagiarism before sending them out for review.

Comment: It happens sometimes that in a paper where several authors contributed chunks of text one of the authors behaved dishonestly with the others not aware of it. Perhaps the corresponding author is trying to make sure this didn't happen.

Answer (score 13):

I've never put such an assertion in one of my own cover letters, and would find it very strange to do so.

- It's assumed that I *should* be behaving honestly and avoiding both plagiarism and self-plagiarism.  Saying: "really, I'm not plagiarizing!" just makes me wonder why the person felt they needed to say anything.
- If I'm *not* behaving honestly, why wouldn't I lie about the results of plagiarism-checking too?

If I saw this as a reviewer, I would think it reflected an odd but almost certainly irrelevant thing about the authors, and then proceed to ignore it.

Comment: This is also what I was thinking. Perhaps the author has been accused of plagiarism in the past.

Comment: And if I was an editor, my first inclination would be "Yeah, I'll be the judge of that, not you..."

Comment: (+1). It reminds me of Pilger's law: *"If it's been officially denied, then it's probably true"*.

Comment: "The lady doth protest too much..."

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate questions here.

1. *Do authors normally check their own papers for plagiarism?* Don't know, but I would assume that it is not that uncommon, especially if they want to preserve their reputation when working with new people who do they not know well.
2. *Do authors put these things into the cover letters?* Absolutely not, this sounds pretty insane and one wonders what was the motivation behind it. Perhaps this was the work of a fresh PhD student, who was required to use Turnitin by his supervisor, just to make sure that he did not plagiarize anything. But I would assume that supervisor would order him to remove such sentence from the cover letter ASAP.